# OpenGL/GLSL varying vectors: How to avoid starburst around vertices?

Tags: opengl, glsl, phong

In OpenGL 2.1, I'm passing a position and normal vector to my vertex shader. The vertex shader then sets a `varying` to the normal vector, so in theory it's linearly interpolating the normals across each triangle. (Which I understand to be the foundation of Phong shading.)

In the fragment shader, I use the normal with Lambert's law to calculate the diffuse reflection. This works as expected, except that the interpolation between vertices looks funny. Specifically, I'm seeing a starburst affect, wherein there are noticeable "hot spots" along the edges between vertices.

Here's an example, not from my own rendering but demonstrating the exact same effect (see the gold sphere partway down the page): 
http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~slongay/pmwiki-2.2.1/pmwiki.php?n=CPSC453W11.Lab12

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) this is a problem with Gauraud shading. But as I understand it, by interpolating the normals and running my lighting calculation per-fragment, I'm using the Phong model, not Gouraud. Is that right?

If I were to use a much finer mesh, I presume that these starbursts would be much less noticeable. But is adding more triangles the only way to solve this problem? I would think there would be a way to get smooth interpolation without the starburst effect. (I've certainly seen perfectly smooth shading on rough meshes elsewhere, such as in 3d Studio Max. But maybe they're doing something more sophisticated than just interpolating normals.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the *exact* same effect. What you are seeing is one of two things.

1. The result of not normalizing the normals before using them in your fragment shader.
2. An optical illusion created by the collision of linear gradients across the edges of triangles. Really.

   The ["Gradient Matters" section at the bottom of this page](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut10%20Fragment%20Lighting.html) (note: in the interest of full disclosure, that's my tutorial) explains the phenomenon in detail. Simple Lambert diffuse reflectance using interpolated normals effectively creates a more-or-less linear light across a triangle. A triangle with a different set of normals will have a different gradient. It will be C0 continuous (the colors along the edges are the same), but not C1 continuous (the colors along the two gradients change at different rates).

   Human vision picks up on gradient differences like these and makes them stand out. Thus, we see them as hard-edges when in fact they are not.

   The only real solution here is to either tessellate the mesh further or use normal maps created from a finer version of the mesh instead of interpolated normals.

Comment: #2 is correct in my situation. Excellent explanation! That makes perfect sense. BTW your tutorial has been extremely helpful to me over the last few months. (I guess this proves I should read *all* of it, as the section you point to does indeed answer my question.)

Comment: So just to clarify, when you suggest using a normal map, I'm assuming you mean feeding it to the fragment shader via a texture unit?

Comment: @Jarrett: Yes, that's the idea. But it's a bit more complicated than that. It's what I'm planning to talk about for tutorial 18. Also, note that having a good diffuse texture map helps; if you're drawing solid colors, it's easy to spot the gradient. If you've got a texture there, the gradient is more difficult to see.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show your code, so its impossible to tell, but the most likely problem would be unnormalized normals in your fragment shader.  The normals calculated in your vertex shader are interpolated, which results in vectors that are not unit length -- so you need to renormalize them in the fragment shader before you calculate your fragment lighting.

Comment: They're definitely normalized.

Comment: Very nasty bug, that. Had me searching for hours once.